# Count of dictionaries in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a `NSMutableArray *objectsArray;` containing dictionaries, each `NSDictionary` have a `"Name"` string with the objects name as value (no surprise). `UITableView` is already sorted using `NSSortDescriptor` by name in ascending order.

Now I need to `section` the TableView using the **name's first letter**, but I cannot find the needed code for:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    /*Return: How many letters from a-z are represented
    as the first letter of the objects name? 
    I.e. If there is no object in the dictionary with name starting with letter B, 
    the number of sections are now 25 if all the other letters are included.*/
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

   //Return: How many objects are starting with each letter
```

So I need to know how to return the correct number of section and rows?

Ps. Is there anything else that I have to do to make this it work, like in cell creation process `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or when passing the `objectsArray` through the `segue` to the `DetailViewController`?

Additional info about app structure:

objectsArray is from a plist array with dictionaries. using a custom prototype cell to populate the Table View. Xcode 4.2 with storyboard. App for iPhone 5.1

Comment: Have you considered actually writing some software to scan through your array and extract the info?

Comment: I have not considered anything. I'm new to programming in general so I don't know how to do stuff if I don't find the tutorial/sample codes that fits my structure and is simple to understand. That's why I'm asking for advice now. Then I will consider the answer. But I guess that is what I need to do when I get some guidelines on how, like @mprivat is getting me started with good answer.

Comment: Frankly, if you're new to programming you shouldn't be programming in Objective-C -- start with something like Java instead.  Starting with Objective-C you'll learn a lot of bad habits and never learn many of the fundamentals.  The world can wait another month or three for the next great viral iPhone app.

Comment: I didn't ask for which programming language to start on. I've been through all that info and I made my choise because I want to develop for iPhone (atm).

Comment: So if you wanted to be a skyscraper builder the first thing you'd build would be Taipei 101?

Comment: I never said I want to be a programmer, I just want to make an iPhone application and it's going very well. This is getting off topic. Bye-bye.

Comment: In other words (based on the fact that you've asked 75 questions here in a relatively brief time), you want folks here to do the programming for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `NSMutableSet` before you sort. Have your comparator store, in your set, the first letter of each Name it encounters as it sorts. Then the number of sections is the size of your set. This way, you pay very little cost since your comparators are already having to iterate through the array anyway.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for simple and explaining answer, gonna get me started. :-)